# Authorize attribute is redirecting me to Login action even If I signed in successfully

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-3.1

I am working on simple login signup in ASP.NET core application. I am using SignInManager class for user to get signin.

[image]

When user tries to login the following function will get executed:

[image]

When the user enters correct credentials it will redirect to index action in home controller. I have added Authorize attribute for privacy action in home controller:

[image]

My question is if I enter correct credentials it is redirecting me to index action in home controller as expected. But if I try to access privacy action in home controller the Authorize attribute is redirecting me to login action in Account controller even if I successfully logged in. What is causing the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

> if I try to access privacy action in home controller the Authorize attribute is redirecting me to login action in Account controller even if I successfully logged in

Please check and make sure you call `app.UseAuthentication()` and `app.UseAuthorization()` [in correct order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#middleware-order) shown as below.

```
app.UseRouting();

            
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();


app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    //...
```